# How to change initial controller in WatchKit app?

Tags: ios, watchkit

In my WatchKit app I need to display one of two interface controllers depending on the state of the containing iOS app. Neither Page-Based nor Hierarchical interfaces suit my needs.

In UIKit I can change `rootViewController` of the window. Can I do similar trick in the WatchKit?

Is there a way to programmatically switch to a different interface controller without animation and make it the "initial controller"?

Comment: I think I can switch interface controllers with `reloadRootControllersWithNames`.

Comment: I probably got even better solution. Instead of using two interface controllers I use just one. In this controller I have two Group objects and I only show one of the groups at a time.

Comment: As far as I know, reloadRootControllersWithNames only works with Page-Based

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are only 2 Interface Controllers in your app, then you can use Groups, and show one group at a time, and hide other based on your conditions.

At run-time, the only way to modify the arrangement of items is to show/hide elements that you already added using interface builder.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 4):

```
let rootControllerIdentifier = "FirstInputInterfaceController"

WKInterfaceController.reloadRootControllers(withNames: [rootControllerIdentifier], contexts: nil)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.